# How to create new tab in add product page backend

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to create new tab in admin panel while adding a product then assign all attribute under that tab

Like i store all custom attribute under that tab

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to do this within the admin area by:

Selecting **Catalog -> Manage Attribute Sets**

Step 2: Select attribute set to edit, and then create a new attribute group within that:

Step 3: Assign attributes to newly created group